# How to make a div responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

How can I change the position of a div smoothly, responsive?

HTML:

```
<div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-search toggle_icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="sidenav">
<center>
<input id="provider-json" />
</center>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        left: 0;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #d54042;
    }

    .sidenav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        left: 52px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
        border-top-right-radius: 8px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; 
        background: #d54042;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #D54042 , #D56769); 
        background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #D54042, #D56769);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #D54042, #D56769);
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #D54042 , #D56769);
    }

    #provider-json {
        margin-top: 6px;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border:solid 1px #ccc;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
        box-shadow: inner 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        outline-color: #d54042;
    }

    .toggle_icon {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        color: white;
        padding: 3px 3px 2px 5px;
    }
```

I would like to change verticaly the position of .icon and .sidenav.
When i make the screen smaller it should go smoothly up to top: 0;

I tried this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.icon, .sidenav {
    top: 5%;
}
}
```

But this works only when the screen is 480px wide.

Comment: Change the `max-width` in the media query if you want to check for other sizes

Answer (score 2):

To give that a `smooth transition`, make use of `css transition` as below,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.icon, .sidenav {
    top: 0;
    transition:0.6s ease; /*Add this*/
}
}
```

This move `icons and search bar` to `top` at screen resolution below `480px;`, check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qjea1g1/)

Comment: Yes, but it changes only at one point and this is 480px. I would like to change the position permanently. So when i make the screen smaller or bigger it sholud go up oder down.

Comment: Yes @GregOstry that's because you have used top:0 in media query, that means following styles should take place at screen resolution below 480px, if you change that to 640px or assign another media query by 5% top then it performs that, for transition as i have used.

Comment: @GregOstry same for top to down, set top:30% to 0 to .icon and .sidenav, this make nav to be fixed at top and then using media query at certain resolution move that down.

Comment: this make sense +1

Comment: Thanks @AamirShahzad :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question "change the place smoothly" I am giving you some idea about `relative` and `absolute` positioning.

According to reference "`Absolute` location is a place's exact spot on a map, while relative location is an estimate of where a place is `in relation to other landmarks.`" What this means relative takes `parent div into consideration` but absolute is totally absolute.

```
 <div class="container">
         <div class="icon">
         <i class="fa fa-search toggle_icon"></i>
       </div>
      <div class="sidenav">
         <center>
         <input id="provider-json" />
         </center>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, refine your code by keeping container with `relative` positioning and other with `absolute`. Relative should always wrap the absolute. Also take some reference from online tutorials like w3schools with better example. You will be cleared with concept.